# How to install rnpm package for react native

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I am trying to install this package for my `react-native` package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dialogs

I see that I need to execute this command to get it installed. `rnpm install --save react-native-dialogs`

I have `node` and `npm` installed on my machine. I am not sure what `rnpm` is. I am getting an error. I tried to go through some links but no luck.

> 'rnpm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the rnpm to npm: `npm install --save react-native-dialogs`. It may works.

**EDIT:**

The solution is installing the **rnpm** (React Native Package Manager): https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm

Comment: See this https://github.com/aakashns/react-native-dialogs some difference If I install through npm, I have to configure manually a lot

Comment: Oh, i see. So, try to install the rnpm (React Native Package Manager) tho: https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm

Answer (score 5):

rnpm has been "absorbed" in to core React Native. If the package is asking you to install via rnpm you can use the following instead

`react-native install --save react-native-dialogs`

This will install the package from npm and then link the native dependencies. It's a shortened version of

`npm install --save react-native-dialogs && react-native link react-native-dialogs`

Comment: --save is not a valid option error: unknown option `--save'

Comment: We can escape --save option, package.json will automatically  updated with dependency.

Answer (score 1):

you should install rnpm

```
$ sudo npm install rnpm -g
```

now you can use rnpm

you can check rnpm document:[rnpm](https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm)